# Insert Videos in presentation

Tags: video, slideshow, microsoft-powerpoint

I do presentations for educational courses (university, college, schools). With many slides, lots of videos and pictures.I had been using WPS presentation software (kingsoft) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; since it allowed me to insert videos. As of now whenever I insert a video or a picture it hangs. I need to reboot the software. This issue persists despite updating the software or reinstalling the software with the latest update

Is there any other software which can

- Be installed on the Linux laptop (free version or open source)
- Has inbuilt slide transitions
- Can insert videos (2 min - 7 min)
- Can handle large pictures
- Has some learning tools or videos for initial hang of the software.

**P.S.** I have tried using Latex Beamer but I am not sure if videos can be inserted and slide transitions are available. TIA

Comment: Why don't you use LibreOffice Impress?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other software which can...

[LibreOffice](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice) Impress is a free program for creating presentations. LibreOffice Impress lets you create multimedia presentations of varying complexity.

In the slides of the presentation can include multimedia objects, 2D and 3D objects, special effects and animation.

LibreOffice Impress provides tools to create diagrams and flowcharts from the links between objects (like LibreOffice Draw). Also there are means for drawing free of objects. To objects you can add different styles, animations and effects.

To create a new presentation, you can use the presentation Wizard, which steps you can choose the options and features of the future presentation.

In Ubuntu, it is installed by default in LibreOffice Package, if you don't have it, try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

You can purge the PPA and downgrade LibreOffice to Ubuntu pre-installed version via command:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

And for running it use the command :

```
libreoffice --impress
```

Comment: I tried using it but then it too is hanging when the video is inserted. I need to manually restart the program and even then so it has the same issue.

Comment: But it works well for me, I think your problem is somewhere else, Impress can handle videos flawlessly.

Comment: I installed it from the software center. Is there any other place to install it from?

Comment: Not when I bought the system. I was working with WPS presentation but that gave me trouble when inserting a video.

Comment: @BRMBU If both programs show the same symptom then the problem is with neither but certainly with the files you're trying to use. Either an incompatible file format/codec or the location of the file needs files system error correction. Can you open and reproduce the video with a video player?

Comment: @GabrielaGracia,. The video is .mp4 format. It plays in vlc. In impress I was asked to install dependencies to play the video which I did. But despite installation the problem still persists.